# Google Apps Script - Get IP of doPost and track in Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

is there an easy way to capture the IP of a d`oPost(e)` request and store it with the incoming values of the POST as to track the origin of the request?

It does not seem to be available via `e.parameter`.

I cannot find a complete list of the other properties or methods of `e`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way today to get the IP Address or the User Agent of the incoming request in `doGet` or `doPost`. Please log an enhancement request in our [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) along with details of your use case.

Comment: Good suggestion, lets all do that.

Comment: Here is the issue URL:https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2569&thanks=2569&ts=1364320993

Comment: *Apr 1, 2013 09:22AM - Status: Won't Fix (Infeasible) - Thank you for your request. Unfortunately, we do not have any plans to support this feature at this time. We may reconsider it in the future if there is sufficient demand.* **Let's keep asking...**